# Trading out Crestron dimmers for standard (non Crestron) 3 way switches

Tags: electrical, wiring

I would like to trade out my current stairway lighting which is Crestron master dimmer/2 slave dimmers and replace them with 3 standard 3 way switches. Once the Crestron units are removed, is the wiring for all the 3 new 3 way switches as usual with hot to common and travelers on the remaining screws?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes please?

Comment: If the three switches are for the same lights, then you'll need 2  3- way switches and a 4-way switch. the 3-way switches would be wired hot to common and two travelers and light to common and two travelers. The 4-way  switches the travelers from both 3-way switches.

Comment: Thanks, problem solved.